# I am facing conflict in jquery ui tooltip and bootstrap.js, so I put the below solution as suggested for new alias and getting the error :-

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Alias Change-
:

```
$.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
```

Now getting  error while calling jQuery tooltip with new alias:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on uitooltip prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'option'...

Here is the code snippet that I am using :-

```
$(this).uitooltip( "option", "content", ""+ $(this).attr("data-content") );
```

where  data-content works well and commenting the above part does well.

Answer (score 0):

The order of things is essential...

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    // handle jQuery plugin naming conflict between jQuery UI and Bootstrap
    $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    $.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

First must come jQuery UI, then the call to `$.widget.bridge`, and then the include of bootstrap.js

Then to init the tooltips, you would use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('mySelector').each(function(ind, ele){
       var $this = $(this),
           myContent = $this.attr("data-content");
       $this.uitooltip({"content":myContent});
    });
});
```

The problem with your original method is that it is using the method to set a option *after* the widget is initialized, not the method to set the option on initialization. The correct way on initialization would be like so:

```
$(this).uitooltip({ "content": ""+ $(this).attr("data-content") });
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I have done it ... The order is  jquery, jquery-ui, widget script and then 
bootstrap.js


Could there be any other reason other than this ?

Comment: @bhasski  I updated the answer to show how to initialize the tooltips correctly.